# classcastexception is getting like integer cannot cast the java.lang.string

Tags: java, hibernate

I have cast as `int` in this query but while run the error is getting     like class cast exception integer

cannot cast the java.lang.string please resolve

```
SELECT  cast(cfd.fd_case_no AS int) as caseNo FROM  InwardBundle ib ,CaseFileDetail cfd WHERE  ib.ib_id IN "
                        + "(SELECT ib_id  from  InwardBundle Where ib_id=:inward_id)"
                        + " and cfd.fd_stage_lid in (236,15,223,225,14,351355,17,235,238,351004)  and cfd.ib_mid = ib.ib_id  order by caseNo
```

Comment: Are you sure that `CaseFileDetail.fd_case_no` contains only numbers? The message seems to say that this column contains arbitrary strings.

Comment: Please ensure the numbers are integers only. '56.72' decimals will give this error.

Comment: yaa only numbers.

Comment: You can't simply **cast** string to integer (in java code), you should instead parse it. Show the code that performs your query. Also did you run this query from SQL console, does it return correct result (integers)?

Comment: yes, i'm run the query db console. its correctly running by order(integers)